# Flutter InAppWebView not authenticated problem

Tags: flutter, authentication, cookies, flutter-inappwebview

I've a flutter app, where I do login with usarname and passoword. As a result of login call I obtain jwt_token and PHPSESSID.
I need them to be authenticated in a webview. So I add this code below, but every time I open this webview it consider me as not authenticated also I add PHPSESSID to cookies and jwt_token to headers and redirect me to login page. Can anyone help me with this problem?
I'm sure 100% that jwt_token and cookie of PHPSESSID are not empty.

```
Widget inAppWebViewCustom(String? cookie, String? jwtToken) {
  late InAppWebViewController  inAppWebViewController;
  CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.instance();

    String? sessionIdFull = cookie?.split(';')[0];
    cookie = sessionIdFull?.split('=')[1];

   cookieManager.setCookie(
    url: Uri.parse('https://mysite.it/1-livello'),
    name: 'PHPSESSID',
    value: cookie ?? '',
    path: '/',
    isSecure: true,
       isHttpOnly: true
  );

  cookieManager.setCookie(
      url: Uri.parse('https://mysite.it/1-livello'),
      name: 'auth',
      value: jwtToken ?? '',
      path: '/',
      isSecure: true,
      isHttpOnly: true
  );

  Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $jwtToken '
  };

  return InAppWebView(
    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
        url: Uri.parse('https://mysite.it/1-livello'),
        headers: requestHeaders,
    ),
    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller){
      inAppWebViewController = controller;
      },
    initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
        ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
            sharedCookiesEnabled: true,
            minimumZoomScale: 1.0,
            maximumZoomScale: 1.0),
        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          javaScriptEnabled: true,
          supportZoom: false,
        ),
    ),
    onTitleChanged: (controller, value)=> {
      print(value),
    },
  );
}
```